# Prisma ORM Postgres SQL DB Schema Not Null Fields

Tags: javascript, postgresql, prisma

Just so you have it here is my defined prisma schema.

Now if I read correctly in the prisma docs it said, that every field in which I do not declare a ? after the type,  it should be presented as not null, in a relational database.
[image: This is the mentioned Section in the Docs.]

```js
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Users {
  id          String      @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt   DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt
  email       String      @unique
  password    String
  role        Roles       @default(USER)
  contact     Contacts?   @relation(fields: [contactId], references: [id])
  contactId   String?
}

enum Roles {
  USER
  ADMIN
}

model Contacts {
  id          String    @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime  @updatedAt
  firstName   String
  lastName    String
  email       String    @unique
  phone       String
  addressLine String
  city        String
  zipCode     Int
  note        String
  Users       Users?
  events      ContactsOnEvents[]  @relation(name: "guest")
  guests      ContactsOnEvents[]  @relation(name: "guestfrom")
}

model Events {
  id          String      @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt   DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt
  name        String
  startDate   DateTime
  EndDate     DateTime
  type        EventTypes  @default(HUNT)
  contacts    ContactsOnEvents[]
}

enum EventTypes {
  HUNT
  EVENT
}

model ContactsOnEvents {
  guest       Contacts  @relation(fields: [guestId], references: [id], name: "guest")
  guestId     String
  guestFrom   Contacts  @relation(fields: [guestFromId], references: [id], name:"guestfrom")
  guestFromId String
  event       Events    @relation(fields: [eventId], references: [id])
  eventId     String
  assignedAt  DateTime  @default(now())
  type        Types[]   

  @@id([guestId, eventId])
}


enum Types {
  HUNTER
  DRIVER
  SEEKER
}
```

So in this schema I think most of the fields should be not null fields, but when I open it in Prisma studio most of my fields are nullable, ist that some sort of config Error or is it another wierd bug.

For Refrence here a picture of my user table where every field except the contact relation should not be null. Instead all Fields are nullable here cause required fields should be red.

[image: Picture of User in prisma studio]

So thanks for the help everyone.

Addition This is my Schema for the Users table itself

[image: Users Table]

After seeing this I of course tried if it would get into the databse and it does.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to save a record through Prisma Studio without adding all the required fields?

Are your database schema and TypeScript types correct?

Comment: Yeah I can add and save the record to the db with null values on required fields, through  Prisma studio as seen in the picture. My Database schema is in the Post and I believe it‘s correct. Haven‘t created any custom types yet. As i first want my db Schema.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the actual schema in your underlying database, not your Prisma schema. I'm curious if it created the `NOT NULL` constraints correctly.

I'll also note that `email` and `password` are the only fields that truly require data to be passed in, since the rest are either optional or have a default value.

Comment: So are these fields like empty strings or are they null and even why won't it mark them red that I need to write something in there on the prisma Studio.

Comment: I think there is a bug in Prisma. I have tried this with about three different databases services which use MySQL and Postgresql and they all fail at the"NOT NULL" constraint. Yet i figured that this only happens within the Prisma Studio. If you insert an empty row in the database itself based on your prisma schema as migrated it will complain about the NOT NULL Constraint violation.  Therefore, i believe the bug dwells in the prisma studio itself

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in Prisma. I have tried this with about three different databases services which use MySQL and PostgreSql and they all fail at the"NOT NULL" constraint. Yet I figured that this only happens within the Prisma Studio. If you insert an empty row in the database itself based on your Prisma schema as migrated it will complain about the NOT NULL Constraint violation. Therefore, I believe the bug dwells in the Prisma studio itself.

If you even try with MongoDB/Superbase the Prisma studio will still insert an empty string even if you set the NOT NULL constraint.

There is a bug in Prisma studio that inserts empty strings when NOT NULL has been set.